# NestJS best way to call an API every day at 12 AM

Tags: nestjs

I need to call an API every day at 12 AM. How can I achieve this using `NestJS`. Any leads, please?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the user is asking  for implementation without showing an effort in making their own first. This is a common use case outlined in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Have you read through the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/task-scheduling)? Seems like this is exactly what you're looking for using a [CRON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) expression.

Comment: Can you please implement with nestjs

Comment: [Read the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/task-scheduling#declarative-cron-jobs)